# Why is data not fully loaded with view(response) in Scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some comments from Youtube with `Scrapy`. However, when I enter the `scrapy shell` mode and open it with `view(response)`, I cannot find any comments but the loading spinner.

`scrapy shell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkl7-NzqxWo`

`view(response)`

Shows me infinite spinner on the comment section. How can I load comments as well so that I could scrape them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Scrapy does not support JS. So comments are loaded with extra request `https://www.youtube.com/comment_service_ajax?action_get_comments=1...` (check Network tab in Chrome devtools panel).

You can:

- check extra requests and parse them
- use Scrapy+Splash
- use other scraping tools, that support JS rendering